# migration of angular 1.5 to angular10 , ngModel is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, mobx

I'm working on migration of angular1.5 to angular10. My current code in angular1.5 with mobx(mobx-angularjs package is being used).

I have used `downgradeComponent` approach.

```
export default angular
.module('test', [])
.directive('myTest', downgradeComponent({component: MyTestComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

## angularjs template

`<input ng-model="$ctrl.store.personname" name="personname" maxlength="40"/>`

## angular10 template

`<input [(ngModel)]="store.personname"  name="personname" maxlength="40"/>`

After changed angular10 template, data binding is not working. Does angular10 expects mobx-angular pacakge instead of mobx-angularjs package?

I tried https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

try to import FomrsModule in your app.module !

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


imports: [

 ....

 FormsModule  , 
]
```

Comment: Thanks Rhibi, It is already there. But not working.